# How corosync, pacemaker and zookeeper are related to each other?

Tags: python, cloud, cluster-computing, high-availability

As I know Corosync is the messaging layer and Pacemaker is the resource manager which starts and stops the services and Zookeeper looks on the services and resources, we register resources and services at zookeeper. Can anyone give me a working example how they work and their working in details....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

**Corosync** is the cluster layer : it allows hosts to discover each others, elect a master and exchange messages

**Pacemaker** is the resource layer : given the state of the cluster provided by Corosync and the resources configuration, it computes where to stop and start the resources. If the state of the cluster changes (when a host is added or removed), Pacemaker decides what to do (for example, move a resource to another host).

Obviously, these two are almost always run together, even if Pacemaker can work with other cluster layers than Corosync.

**Zookeeper** is not direcly related with the Corosync/Pacemaker stack. It is a distributed configuration service. It provides several primitives that allows programs to :

- Share a common configuration (you can see it like a key/value store)
- Handle cluster membership (who is connected, who is not, who registered in a group, for instance)
- Make elections
- Share locks
- Exchange messages via queues
- Etc... A lot of interesting things can be done using the Zookeeper primitives. See https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.0-alpha/recipes.html for example.

When you create a program, and then run it in a redundant/distributed way using Pacemaker/Corosync, you can use Zookeeper to share its configuration, elect a master, share locks etc. But other systems exists, it depends on what are your needs (for example if you only need queues, an AMQP server will be better, or if you need to store a lot of key/value data, a NOSQL server might be more appropriate).